# Download GitLab CI artifacts from a given job identifier/name, in a given commit, regardless of the pipeline status

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I have a pipeline in GitLab CI. To simplify the question, let's say it has 3 stages: `assemble`, `deploy`, and `report` — that run in that order.

The `assemble` stage has only one job — `assemble:release`. The `deploy` stage has two *manual* jobs — `deploy:dev` and `deploy:prod`.

When `deploy:dev` is triggered, it just runs a `cURL` command to start another pipeline in a different system with some reference data from GitLab CI — this is something I can't change.

My problem is that I need to be able to download the artifacts created by `assemble:release`. There are a few ways to do this using the GitLab CI API, but I haven't found a successfully way to accomplish this.

The URI I'm currently using is: `https://server-name.tld/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/jobs/artifacts/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}/download?job=assemble:release`, but because the status of the pipeline is not successful yet a that point, it doesn't download the correct file(s). I'm aware there are other resources, like using the `job_id`, but it is quite tricky to resolve the correct `job identifier` when on a different job/step.

The ideal solution for me would be to trigger something like: `https://server-name.tld/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/jobs/artifacts/${CI_COMMIT_HASH_ID}/download?job=assemble:release` — regardless of the pipeline status.

Any ideas how to accomplish this, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm aware there are other resources, like using the job_id, but it is quite tricky to resolve the correct job identifier when on a different job/step.

One strategy you can use is configure `assemble:release` to pass along its job ID to the `deploy:dev` job, so that it can pass that information when triggering the pipeline in the external system. That way, you don't need to *resolve* that information -- you can pass it explicitly between your jobs and to the external system.

Making some assumptions, maybe your configuration could look like this, using `artifacts:dotenv:` to pass the release job information:

```yaml
stages:
  - assemble
  - deploy
assemble:release:
  stage: assemble
  script:
    # ...
    - echo "RELEASE_JOB_ID=${CI_JOB_ID}" > release-info.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: release-info.env

deploy:dev:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Release job ID was ${RELEASE_JOB_ID}"
    - artifact_url="${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/jobs/${RELEASE_JOB_ID}/artifacts"
    # or whatever, adjust as needed
    - trigger-jenkins.sh ... --release-artifact-url="$artifact_url"
```

Then your external pipeline can download the artifact using the provided URL or job id.